# Displaying web images valid excuse for using NSAllowsArbitraryLoads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, app-store-connect, app-transport-security

Until now, we have only been setting `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` in our app's ATS settings.

However,  are now introducing link previews in our chat functionality. Links posted by a user are used to create a preview containing both the linked webpage's image and favicon.

The problem is that some links posted by users have favicons/images in clear-text (HTTP) format.

Is this a valid reason for using `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`?

I am not 100% sure on the current status of ATS enforcement and whether user-generated links would be an acceptable exception.

*(We are using the Kingfisher library to display these images in a UIImageView so `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia` with AVFoundation is not possible.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I cannot be certain what Apple will consider a valid reason (since they haven't started enforcing, so we have no information to go off of), having user driven content in the app seems like it would be one of those scenarios that would require the broader `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` exception.

What I would recommend, in order to show Apple that you've done all that you can to secure any communication you can, would be to do the opposite of the most common technique.  Normally, apps will leave ATS enabled (by leaving the default of `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` as NO) while adding exception domains that disable ATS for certain domains.  If I were you, I would do the opposite - set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to YES, since you can't know what URLS might need ATS exceptions, then add exception domains for the domains that you control in the app (assuming there is some main server you get most of the app content from).  This ensures communications with your server are secured using ATS standards, while all outside of the known servers will be exempt from ATS requirements.So turn ATS off, but turn it back on for domains in your control.

From this [great article](https://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/) on some common ATS configurations, you can see how you would set things up this way ("Example C: ATS disabled, with some exceptions"):

[image]

To me, this would be a good sign to Apple that you are trying as much as possible to comply with the spirit of ATS.

Comment: Good idea on using exception domains on our own backend services!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be rejected. The last update from Apple on this deadline was this:

> At WWDC 2016 we announced that apps submitted to the App Store will be
>   required to support ATS at the end of the year. To give you additional
>   time to prepare, this deadline has been extended and we will provide
>   another update when a new deadline is confirmed.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12212016b

Comment: Can't see any new deadline information yet, but would prefer not to use it if it would mean we have to do an app update in the future. 
Does this mean the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` would not be allowed when we are required to support ATS?

Comment: Apple hasn't publicly stated what their new policy will be.

The proposed policy was that "reasonable justification" would be required to disable ATS. Only Apple can tell us what that will mean :-).